# Is it possible to implement artificial intelligence concept in jquery?

Tags: jquery, artificial-intelligence

**Is it possible to implement artificial intelligence concept in jquery?**

Comment: This question needs elaboration.

Comment: I was thinking about the n gram model to create a grammar from a webpage, doing it with node.js + jquery + jsdom would be a piece of cake

Comment: I wonder why this question is still open, but try this [JavaScript for Artificial Intelligence](http://mind.sourceforge.net/js.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery is build upon Javascript. Javascript is a Turing complete language. You can implement artificial intelligence concepts in any Turing complete language.

Comment: Why do we need a turing complete language to do AI stuff?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the question seems to be answered by the other guys:

1. jQuery isn't a programming language but a DOM traversing and manipulation library. (Helps you select and manipulate stuff in an HTML page)
2. jquery is written in JavaScript. You could program something in JS and then use jQuery to help you display the result in a browser. Perhaps that's what you meant in the first place?

But, out of personal curiosity, what exactly do you want to do? What programming language you use for the AI part should depend on what you are familiar with and what you use for input and output.
Unless you want to write an Expert System or a Decision Engine, you might want use the language that the rest of the program is written in.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, though jQuery won't help you any with this...it's for DOM operations, but plain JavaScript has everything you need as a turing complete language.

I'm not saying it's the *best* platform (because of performance, etc...it's definitely *not* a great platform IMO, but it has some advantages).  But...is it *possible*? Sure.

Answer (score 0):

jquery is a library written in the javascript language.

It would be possible to implement many artificial intelligence concepts in javascript, but I think the best route would be to use a language more common in the field, such as [LISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29).